Newly Raydium tokens
"I'm facing an issue with my bot that buys newly listed tokens on Raydium using a webhook. The bot continuously monitors and buys new tokens, but after buying 8 to 10 tokens or running for 30 minutes, it stops purchasing. When I restart the bot, it works again and then stops after a while. What could be causing this issue? Is it related to Raydium or something else?
